# AspNetCore 2.1 Bearer Token Authentication - Current user is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt, entity-framework-core

I've an application that requests a token when the user signs in.
That token is then passed with the following header:

```
Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>
```

I've the following code on my `startup.cs` (aspnet core 2.1):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvcCore()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest)
            .AddFormatterMappings()
            .AddJsonFormatters()
            .AddCors()
            .AddAuthorization(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                 .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                 .Build();
            });

    /* Code... */

    ConfigureAuthentication(services);

    /* Code... */
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication()
       .UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>(container)
       .UseCors(x =>
       {
           x.WithOrigins("*")
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowCredentials()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .Build();
       });

    /* Code... */
}

private void ConfigureAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        var tokenProvider = new HumbleTokenProvider(container);
        options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenProvider.GetValidationParameters();
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });
}
```

To create tokens when the user sign in, I've `TokenProvider` service:

```
public class RsaJwtTokenProvider : ITokenProvider
{
    readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    readonly IDateFactory dateFactory;

    readonly RsaSecurityKey _key;
    readonly string _algorithm;
    readonly string _issuer;
    readonly string _audience;

    public RsaJwtTokenProvider(
            IConfiguration configuration,
            IDateFactory dateFactory
        )
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.dateFactory = dateFactory;

        var parameters = new CspParameters { KeyContainerName = configuration.GetSection("TokenAuthentication:SecretKey").Value };
        var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, parameters);

        _key = new RsaSecurityKey(provider);

        _algorithm = SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature;
        _issuer = configuration.GetSection("TokenAuthentication:Issuer").Value;
        _audience = configuration.GetSection("TokenAuthentication:Audience").Value;
    }

    public (string Token, int Expires) CreateToken(string userName, string UserId)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, UserId),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName)
        };

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "jwt");

        int expiresIn = int.Parse(configuration.GetSection("TokenAuthentication:Validaty").Value);
        DateTime expires = dateFactory.Now.AddMinutes(expiresIn).ToUniversalTime();
        SecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Audience = _audience,
            Issuer = _issuer,
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_key, _algorithm),
            Expires = expires,
            Subject = identity
        });

        return (tokenHandler.WriteToken(token), expiresIn);
    }

    public TokenValidationParameters GetValidationParameters()
    {

        return new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // The signing key must match!
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = _key,

            // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = _issuer,
            // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = _audience,

            // Validate the token expiry
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            // If you want to allow a certain amount of clock drift, set that here:
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see, `TokenValidationParameters` used in `AddJwtBearer` is provided by the code above `GetValidationParameters`.

My first perception on this, was that none of the `startup` authorization/authentication methods checked for the token, or at least I'm not providing it besides the `TokenValidationParameters`.

I assumed that it worked because of the Token composition and the service would decompose it to extract the current user and insert it into Identity.

**However**, when I call `userManager.GetUserId(user)` it returns null.

```
public string CurrentUser
{
    get
    {
        var user = accessor.HttpContext?.User;
        if (user != null)
            return userManager.GetUserId(user);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The content of user is the following:

[image: S1]
[image: S2]

What am I doing wrong?

**Screenshot Claims (Token creation)**

[image: S3]

**Update**

With the help of [Mohammed Noureldin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988508/mohammed-noureldin) I've discovered that I didn't have claims in my `CurrentUser` property.

After putting `[Authorize]` in my controller it started working.
However, I need it to work on anonymous actions too...
Any idea?

Comment: I am not sure what is your exact problem. Is your problem that you are not able to get who is the current logged in User from the Identity?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin yes that's it

Comment: Ok then please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you are not able to get who is the current logged in `User` from the `Identity`.

You need to add `Name` claim to your `ClaimsIdentity`, which will automatically be translated to `Name` property of `Identity` property.

Here is an example:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "SomeName or Id")
};
```

and add any other claim you need to this list, and then create your `ClaimsIdentity`:

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "jwt");
```

### UPDATE:

I did not notice before that you are trying to add `Claims` (and the whole `Identity`) inside your authorization process. That is not how it should be. Adding claims should happen inside authentication, not authorization.

Comment: Ok I see, missed that somehow... I'll try and give you feedback asap.

Comment: After applying that to my `CreateToken`, my `userManager` still retrieves null.
I will update my code with that.

Comment: @LeandroSoares, is your `Name` property populated now?

Comment: I think so... Check the screenshot at the end of the question.

Comment: @LeandroSoares, please show also the Name property (`User` -> `Identity` -> `Name`)

Comment: @LeandroSoares, could you please also try `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` instread of `ClaimTypes.Name`?

Comment: My CurrentUser's name? it's null, it has no claims

Comment: I'm using both Name and NameIdentifier

Comment: @LeandroSoares, I am not sure now why you still get null, I will take a look at it again when I finish working. In the mean while, I suggest taking a look on the source code of `GetUserId` function trying to discover why you get null.

Comment: Hey, It's working... but check my "Update" section please

Comment: @LeandroSoares Nice to hear that (even partially), I see that you are adding your claims in the outside of your `AuthenticationHander` (you are doing this during authorization process)? Claims addition is part of the authentication process (not authorization), therefore they should be added in your `AuthenticationHandler`. If you are not sure where is that happening, check which handler is being used in `AddJwtBearer` function in your `startup` code.

Comment: I'm not sure where `AuthenticationHeader` is... I've my `AddJwtBearer` in the question. Do I need add anything there?

Comment: @LeandroSoares, I did not notice at first that you are trying to add Claims (and the whole identity) inside your authorization process. That is not how it should be. I guess you wanted to do something and used the wrong way to do it. Could you please describe what you want to achieve exactly (the whole idea)? Maybe I can help you more. For the being time, you cannot do anything else, as I said. Adding claims should happen inside authentication, not authorization.

Comment: I see... What you call Authorization it's where I create my token? How do I add claims to that `AddJwtBearer`?

Comment: @LeandroSoares, it should be done by the `AuthenticationHandler` itself. You are attaching the handler to your application by this line of code `AddJwtBearer()` in your startup code. If that handler is not adding the claims to your User, that means something is going wrong in your authentication process. Or if you are doing something custom and you know exactly that you are doing something that cannot be done with the standard JwtHandler, then you may want to write your own handler (I guess you do not want to write your custom handler, but I just mentioned that).

Comment: @LeandroSoares, you may check the source code of the AuthenticationHandler to see how it exactly adds the `Claims` and creates the whole `Identity`

Comment: @LeandroSoares, at this point I am not sure if I am completely right. I hoped that somesome contributes in this discussion to ensure that I am correct here. My answer and comments depends on what I know (that may be right and may be wrong) :).

Comment: @LeandroSoares, can I help somehow further?

Comment: I sticked with the `[Authorize]` option, thank you anyway